# Crystal Report Version=11.5.3700.0

Tags: crystal-reports

Error is:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Design,  Version=11.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

My web.config is:

This is a existing project. i already tried to sort out the problem using

http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/us2_default.asp link. but i ineed Version=11.5.3700.0 assembly.

Please give me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are compiling against a different version to the one that you are getting from that installation (that one is probably newer). This usually means that you have a version of the dlls in the GAC which is causing compilation to be against those dlls. You probably need to remove the dlls from the GAC and then install the version that you can redistribute on all of the development machines.

Answer (score 0):

On the useful page [SAP WIKI](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports+2008+(and+9.1,+XI+R1,+XI+R2)+-+Version+and+Download+information+for+Service+Packs?original_fqdn=wiki.sdn.sap.com) it's not clearly visible,
but CR 11.5 R2 SP6 has two assembly versions, 
11.5.3300 for .NET 1.1 and 11.5.3700 for .NET 2.0.